# Trimming the leading THE in SQL results on Joomla module Articles Category

Tags: sql, joomla, trim

I am trying to trim the leading "the" in a query that returns the titles of articles in Joomla, so that results are displayed in alphabetical order and the leading "the", if present, is disregarded. The module responsible for this is the Article Category (which is Joomla core module) and the file I think I should modify is helper.php in modules/mod_articles_category.
I replace the following line:

```
  $articles->setState('list.direction', $params->get('article_ordering_direction',    
  'ASC'));
```

With this:

```
  $articles->setState('list.direction', $params->get('article_ordering_direction',  
  'TRIM(LEADING \'THE \' FROM a.title) ASC'));
```

However, if I enable the debug mode, the TRIM is not showing. SO I guess, that I need to make the change somewhere else. Sorry but I am not familiar with Joomla so don't really know where this query is coming from. Any pointer is very much appreciated.

Comment: The TRIM function should go to SELECT statement not ORDER. Also I'm sure it's not the correct file, and I'd say you can't do what you need with the framework. Why not forking it to your own module which uses your own SQL query

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the short answer is no, I don't believe you can modify a query from a module, just like this. I haven't worked with modules, but I have some experience with components, so I would suggest two approaches:

- Try to query the database yourself from the module, not by using setState, but building the query yourself.
- You can *cheat*. Since Joomla has already done the heavy lifting for you, you could just manipulate the result object (i.e. $list) rearranging it and stripping off whatever you don't want. I would also suggest that you treat your code as a layout override, that way you'll be able to update your site without overriding the changes you have made.